# Argument of type "int" cannot be assigned to parameter "__s" of type "slice" in function "__setitem__" "int" is incompatible with "slice"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, nonetype

My code is running perfeclty with no errors from python shell but in VS Code IDE it is highlighting `geeks[i] = None` as error and giving the above(title) as problem/error.

Python:

```python
geeks = [6, 0, 4, 1]
i = 0
while i < len(geeks):
    geeks[i] = None
    i += 1
geeks = [x for x in geeks if x is not None]
print(geeks)
```

Aim of code is to remove all the element from the list .

I know various way by which it could be done but was curious why this happend in VS Code & how to solve this ?

Is there any problem that could occur later ?

the code runs fine but VS Code IDE shows it as error

Answer (score 3):

the variable `geeks` has type `list[int]`, deduced by PyLance static analysis.

The other error message you get is more descriptive of the reason

```
Argument of type "None" cannot be assigned to parameter "__o"
of type "Iterable[int]" in function "__setitem__" 
"__iter__" is not present
```

Adding a `None` to this list is not allowed.

If you give `geeks` the correct type the error is gone

```py
from typing import List, Union

geeks: List[Union[int, None]] = [6, 0, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score -3):

To solve this, you can just click on curly braces on blue bottom panel, then switch type checking to off.

As far as I'm concerned, this happens because VS code sees you try to assign `None` to an item of `List[int]`. I don't think, it may cause any problems in future, but having warnings and  errors just is not great.